# ASP.NET and incomplete HTTP requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, http, iis-7.5

We have an ASP.NET application that handles user uploaded files.
Browser sends a (multi-part) POST request. We have a simple HttpHandler and use HttpRequest.Files to access the uploaded file. It is running on IIS7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

Occasionally, we see an error that the colletion contains 0 files. Upon inspecting HttpRequest.InputStream we see that
we have an incomplete POST request. The Content-Length header indicates there should be more data, than there is.

We manage to reproduce it using Fiddler:
- sending a request with requestBody < Content-Length. 
- The application hangs on the first reference to HttpRequest.Params. 
- Terminate Fiddler, that closes the connection and application resumes. The application logic  as the body is incomplete (0 files).

I assume this is a scenario we have to deal with and can't do much about. After all the browser may close connection any time.

I wonder if there is some switch that would prevent IIS to hand-off incomplete POST request to the application layer (i.e. some buffer). This would eliminate some noise in the ApplicationLayer error monitoring.

Thanks,
Piotr

Comment: what's the size of the files being uploaded? by default IIS has a request length max size and there's another maxRequestLength parameter that can be set in web.config in order to let the app accept bigger requests. Could this have something to do with your problem?

Comment: @Th0rndike: In the repro scenario above the file was tiny (< 1KB). Our settings are maxRequestLength="110000", maxAllowedContentLength="200000000"

On production we're seeing this for anything between 10Kb and tens of Mbs. I suspect the issue is not related to these request limits, though.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

For what I know any limit imposed by IIS can be easily reached with hacking "Slow HTTP Post" Denial os Service (DoS) attack.
the hacker creates multiple instance of the service sending small incomplete requests (without .RequestBody CRL termination).

This kind of attack left open the link that is waiting the incomplete part. If a bot does this, it never will send the remaining part, exceeding the limit returning "Deny of Service".

Probabily your uploaded file is 0 bytes because the site could be under attack and can't complete the request.

In any case to prevent DoS attack need to check programmatically the incomplete requests and kill them

take a look here

http://omaralzabir.com/prevent_denial_of_service__dos__attacks_in_your_web_application/